# HA Proxy closes TCP socket after 10min?

Tags: haproxy

I just started experimenting with HA Proxy in front of my app for hot failovers. I noticed that it is closing a websocket after ~10min from opening the web client to the server.

How can I disable a timeout to keep the websocket open? I can confirm that both boxes are *indeed* up the entire time. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change "timeout server" and "timeout client" to fit your needs. You must never ever run without timeouts, because from time to time you'll have some users disconnect from the net, and these fantom connections will slowly accumulate until you have to restart haproxy, which makes no sense. Better use large timeouts (eg: one day).

Comment: Great thanks! for some reason I was "challenged" figuring out those params

Comment: BTW if you're interested, I have just released 1.5-dev10 which brings "timeout tunnel" for use cases like yours.

Comment: Ooh fascinating I will definitely check it out :) Thanks!

Comment: Btw where is dev10 available? Didn't see it in the nightlies :)